# Main Activity force closes

Tags: android

```
public class androStrategy extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
    View game_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_startGame);
    game_start.setOnClickListener(this);
    View save_exit = findViewById(R.id.btn_SaveExit);
    save_exit.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_Help);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}
 // ...

 public void onClick(View v) 
 {
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
    case R.id.btn_Help:
       Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, about.class);
       startActivity(helpIntent);

        break;
    // More buttons go here (if any) ...

    case R.id.btn_startGame:
        Intent gameIntent = new Intent (this, Game.class);
        startActivity(gameIntent);
       break;

    case R.id.btn_SaveExit:
       finish();
       break;

    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
  super.onPause();
 }

 @Override 
 public void onResume()
 {
     super.onResume();
 }

}
```

Why is that code stopped work?
It worked before and I did NOT change ANYTHYNG here.
I tried to comment
Intent gameIntent = new Intent (this, Game.class);
startActivity(gameIntent);
to see if this will work, and its not.

Well im tired of random-error of java.
Now it works after i take a coffee it doesnt.

Comment: Can you post your LogCat error output?

Comment: I hope you're using LogCat, if so, post the exception you are getting.

Comment: Code doesn't break randomly (unless you have random numbers doing critical tasks).  What's the stack trace?

Comment: 06-27 23:24:06.543: WARN/dalvikvm(2090): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
06-27 23:24:06.543: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2090): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-27 23:24:06.613: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2090): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androstrategy/com.androstrategy.androStrategy}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you post the whole stack trace? (**Edit the question** and put it there instead). BTW, if you're sure you didn't edit the source code, try copying the content of the XML layout file(s), delete the file, create a new file with the same name as the old one (and put the content in it). That usually does the trick for me when something stops working at *random*, but without the rest of the stack trace, it's hard to tell.

Comment: ok, ill copy trace. but as i said if i delete the whole code, it works fine... it stopped working after i took a coffee..

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your main layout, I can only see a couple issues that could be causing this:

```
View game_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_startGame);
```

If those are buttons, cast them as buttons like this:

```
Button game_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_startGame);
```

Also,

```
Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, about.class);
```

Your About class should start with a capital which leads me to believe this is a typo and could be the culprit of your null error.

Comment: there is absolutely no typo. i checked and i had this typo problem with intent before so i included this error in my mind and checked.

Comment: u see i did not change ANY thing here, but it doesnt work. i have a backup of working copy(compilled) and it has the same problem. but before it worked so idunno...

Comment: Well typo or not you should start your class names with a capital letter. And you should cast your buttons as buttons.